# Bind OracleJet ojtimeline component to viewModel

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, oracle-jet

I am trying to understand how I can bind data from the view-model to the view. The `REST` request to the back-end is working fine and I get a JSON array with several items. The existing [documentation](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/uiComponents-timeline-basicTimeline.html) doesn't give me enough help.

How can I bind the timeline component `ojtimeline` to the view-model data array?

**Edit**: No errors now, since the view recognize the view-model array. But the `ojtimeline` doesn't display the data, only a working empty view component.

View

```
<div id="tline"
     data-bind='ojComponent: {
        component: "ojTimeline",
        minorAxis: {
            scale: "hours",
            zoomOrder: ["hours", "days", "weeks"]
        },
        majorAxis: {
        scale: "weeks"
        },
        start: new Date("Jan 1, 2016").toISOString(),
        end: new Date("Jun 31, 2016").toISOString(),
    referenceObjects: [{value: new Date("Feb 1, 2010").toISOString()}],
    series: [{ 
        id: "id",
        emptyText: "No Data.",
        items: statusArray,
        label: "Oracle Events"
    }],
  overview: {
    rendered: "off"
  }                                         
}' style="width: '100%';height: 350px"></div>
```

View-model

```
define(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'jquery', 'ojs/ojknockout', 'ojs/ojtimeline'],
        function (oj, ko) {
            /**
             * The view model for the main content view template
             */
            function timelineContentViewModel() {
                var self = this;
                this.statusArray = ko.observableArray([]);

                self.addData = function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost:8080/myproject/rest/status/v1/findAll",
                        type: 'GET',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            var x = data;
                            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                                statusArray.push({
                                    id: data[i].id,
                                    description: data[i].text,
                                    title: data[i].user.screenName,
                                    start: data[i].createdAt});
                            }
                            //$("#tline").ojTimeline("refresh"); Doesn't have ant affect
                        }
                    });
                };
                self.addData();

            }
            return timelineContentViewModel;
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The ReferenceError is caused by

`var statusArray = ko.observableArray([]);`

it should be

`this.statusArray = ko.observableArray([])`

You will also (probably) need to refresh the timeline when the observable array has changed, e.g. after the for-loop in success callback:

```
...
success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        var x = data;
                        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                            self.statusArray.push({
                                id: data[i].id,
                                description: data[i].text,
                                title: data[i].user.screenName,
                                start: data[i].createdAt});
                        }
                    $("#tline").ojTimeline("refresh");
                    }
...
```

Comment: Yes the statusArray is now known in the view, but the timline is empty. The refresh didn't work.

Comment: Would be nice if you update your code above to fully reflect current state. Are there any errors in console? The approach from my comment worked in cookbook just fine

Comment: Updated the code, the remaining problem is that the timeline component doesn't recognize the data in the array I guess.

Comment: Thanks, are you sure that the for-loop works correctly? Have you debugged it to make sure that "statusArray" contains expected data? Btw you will need to call the refresh as I wrote earlier...

Answer (score 0):

I have loaded `ojTimeline` from Ajax data and have never needed to use refresh. Worst case, you can wrap the `ojTimeline` in a `<!-- ko if ... -->` so that the timeline doesn't appear until you have an Ajax response.

For the `ojTimeline` `items` attribute, instead of referencing the observable, I had to unwrap the observable like this: `items: ko.toJS(statusArray)`.

Another thing to consider is pushing into an `ko.observableArray` inside a `for` loop. Each push using the `ko.observableArray` `push()` method invokes subscriptions. If your array is bound to the UI, then each push will trigger a DOM change. Instead, it is often better to push into the underlying array (unwrap the array) and then invoke `self.statusArray.valueHasMutated`. You may also want to keep an eye on your use of `this`, `self`, and nothing. Consistency will help avoid bugs like the one ladar identified.

What do you think about rewriting your for loop like this (code untested)?

```
ko.utils.arrayPushAll(
  self.statusArray(),
  ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(item) {
    return {
      id: item.id,
      description: item.text,
      title: item.user.screenName,
      start: item.createdAt;
    };
  });
);

self.statusArray.valueHasMutated();
```

Or, if you can get away with it (some OJ components don't like this approach), you can skip the push and just replace the entire array inside the observable:

```
self.statusArray(
  ko.utils.arrayMap(data, function(item) {
    return {
      id: item.id,
      description: item.text,
      title: item.user.screenName,
      start: item.createdAt;
    };
  });
);
```